# Do I need a database for this application?

Tags: sql, database, tree

I have a very large amount of data that would most naturally be represented as a tree:

```
Category 1
    Sub-category 1
        data point 1
            attribute 1
    Sub-cateogry 2
        data point 1
            attribute 1     
            attribute 2
        data point 2
Category 2
    Sub-category 1
        Sub-category 1
            data point 1
        Sub-category 2
            data point 1
            data point 2
    Sub-category 2
        data point 1
        data point 2
        data point 3
...
```

The individual data points have text and numerical attributes, bit it doesn't really suited for representation as a set of related tables.  I would like to be able to perform SQL-like queries, but I would also like to be able to browse through the data in a way that makes the tree structure of the data obvious, like with a file manager.

There's probably some class of application that is ideal for such a thing, but it isn't occurring to me at the moment.  Some kind of combination of a database and a tree viewer control?  Anyone know what it is I'm looking for?  As always, I'm terrified of asking a question in the wrong forum, but I see some related questions here at stackoverflow, so hopefully it's OK.  Thanks!

Comment: Your question isnt clear. You need a db if you want store data, doesnt matter what kind data. Now do you want to know how create a table to store that data? Or How access the data and show in your app?

Comment: Well, *do* you need a database?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I actually don't know if I need a database or not.  For example, a simple spreadsheet is one alternative.  What I need seems to be neither of those exactly.  In particular, the need for a tree-like view seems unusual.  I suppose I could embed some kind of tree viewer within a database with a single table, but that doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Well, 'can' you implement this *without* a database? If so then it clearly isn't 'needed'. Even if able to implement such *without* a database, what are the advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: In any case, Relational Databases can handle generic/uniform trees (where each row represents a "node") - usually through some variation of a nest-set, parent-child-relation, or materialized-path. Alternatively, consider the very relational nature of a SQL DB forms trees where such "nodes" (eg. Users has-many Posts has-many Comments) differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a table like this

- id
- name
- parent_id

This structure would allow for nested categories

You could then make a table that relates category and data points.

Comment: So each node in the tree is just a separate table in the database and then there's one big table for the leaf nodes?  I suppose that could work.  It still doesn't seem like I could browse the data very easily.  Maybe my problem is just that I need to look at data visualization approaches for databases.

Comment: @user3268289 In the above scheme each category (be it a parent category or sub category of sub-sub category or sub-sub-sub ..) is merely a row in the *same* table. At some point there will be meaingful links out - eg. there might be a Categories (tree structure internally, nodes) table and an Items table (edge nodes, leaves). There is no reason why a table can't self-reference itself and then be referenced elsewhere.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  So one table for internal nodes and one table for leaf nodes?  There we go, you just answered my question.  That's a pretty good idea, and an approach that I had not thought of.  Any ideas regarding visualization of everything with an "interactive" tree like in a file browser?

Comment: @user3268289 That is one approach, which works for something like a [BOM (Bill of Material model)](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/11/06/bill-of-materials-the-basics.aspx) or "infinite nesting".. On the other hand, if the categories are a [small] *absolutely fixed set* of levels then it might make sense to make each "level" a separate table.

Comment: The terms "hierarchical data" and "adjacency lists" are what I couldn't think of, but not surprisingly, are major topics in database design.  I think I at least know where to start researching this now.  Thanks everyone, I appreciate it!

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this and happens to be using Access, check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/597302/A-Tree-View-Control-Using-an-MS-Access-Table-and-F.

Answer (score 0):

The java.swing packages contain several table and tree solutions such as the JTable and JTree classes.  JTree can be easily constructed to produce the tree structure you are looking for (looks like a file directory.)

The JTable class can be used to create sortable and searchable tables, although you would have to borrow or write your own sort & search methods.

Although these are from Java, other languages offer similar structures that may serve your needs without using a database.  That being said, "mySQL" is a very easy to use database and you can download the community DB package for free.